# Javascript clearInterval with interval Id doesn't work in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I implemented a timer which works fine but the only problem is that it doesn't clearInterval when the timer ends .

My code looks like this :

```
  const [currentCount, setCurrentCount] = React.useState(10);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = React.useState(10);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
    setIntervalId(intervalId);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  const timer = () => {
    setCurrentCount((prev) => {
      if (prev > 0) {
        return prev - 1;
      } else if (prev === 0) {
        console.log("Still Runs");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return prev;
      }
    });
  };
```

The value of currentCount decreases from 10 to 0 but I want to clear the interval when it reaches 0 and I tried to clear it with this piece of code `clearInterval(intervalId)` but didn't work .

How can I clearInterval when the value of currentCount reaches 0 ?

Comment: Why are you invoking setInterval again in line no. 4 ? While declaring the setInterval in 1 Line it's done .... [ Consider form useEffect ! ]

Comment: Consider this little [vanila js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbdLscnm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook is missing an important dependency from its dependency array: `timer`. To make things simpler on yourself, you can move the `timer` variable inside the effect (unless you have a good reason for it to be outside). This ends up having the added bonus that the `timer` function will be able to reference the interval ID without maintaining it in state.

```
const [currentCount, setCurrentCount] = React.useState(10);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const timer = () => {
    setCurrentCount((prev) => {
      if (prev > 0) {
        return prev - 1;
      } else if (prev === 0) {
        console.log("Still Runs");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return prev;
      }
    });
  };
  const intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked and a quick question how can I run this interval from a function with a button onClick and clearInterval at the end ?

Comment: @MahdiFaraji one option is to make the button control the count state and then add the count to the effect dependency array. Note that if your effect depends on the count variable, you can switch it `setTimeout` and just create a new timeout each time: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ride-vej0k?file=/src/App.js